# I am trying to build apk of my Flutter project but an error occurs and it fails to build

Tags: flutter

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK
size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource compilation failed
  >       F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  ```
  F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
  ```

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource compilation failed
  >       F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  ```
  F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
  ```

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource compilation failed
  >       F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  ```
  F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
  ```

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource compilation failed
  >       F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  ```
  F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
  ```
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 29s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     152.6s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

F:\flutter_projects\i_am_rich>

Comment: Hi, I think you messed up with the icon files of your app. Try to replace the icon files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messed up with the icon files of your app. Try to replace the icon files.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the https://appicon.co/ website to create the application icon, you must choose an image of png

Answer (score 1):

Path:- Your_project_name\android\app\build.gradle

```
android {
   aaptOptions {  
        cruncherEnabled = false  
    }
}
```

in your android section just add this line

Comment: For future readers, This is not a good practice. Do not do this. This might make the error go away, but your APK or app bundle could end up being larger because the images are not being optimized.

Answer (score 0):

in your android\app\main\AndroidManifext.xml  file

add this section:

```
<meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
  />
```

then write the command:
flutter build apk --split-per-abi

notice that there is a section named meta-data , ignore it (do not put the above section in it)